# php - curl and source

Tags: php, curl

Why I get empty source? When I uncommit

```
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.onet.pl');
```

and commit

```
'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch',
```

everything works fine for www.onet.pl. Why it doesn't work for www.ebok.pl (?

```
<?php

    $COOKIEFILE = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../data/config/ebok.txt';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $COOKIEFILE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $COOKIEFILE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
                                              'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml', 
                                              'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch', 
                                              'Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',                                              
                                              'Connection: keep-alive',
                                              'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36')
                                              );
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.ebok.pl');        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ssl.plusgsm.pl/ebok-web/');        
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.onet.pl');        
    echo curl_exec($ch);


?>
```

I need to log-in to this page.

Comment: have you tried `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

Comment: I have tried with
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
but the same, notning...

Comment: set return transfer to 1 and see what you get

Comment: the same. Nothig. Is this code working on your computer?

Comment: What's in `../data/config/ebok.txt`, by the way?

Comment: This is for cookie. Now this file not exist. I can change this path, but I think this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If something isn't working right, there's almost always a way to find out why.  In curl's case, `curl_error` will tell you.

If i change your `curl_exec` line to instead say

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false) die(curl_error($ch));
```

I get this:

```
[cHao@hydra-vm ~]$ php curl.php
error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac%
```

Looks like this has something to do with the server doing SSL/TLS handshaking incorrectly, but i don't know enough about curl or SSL to say for sure.

Reason #15 to *always check the result from functions that can return errors*.

Either way, if i force the SSL version to TLS v1.0, like so:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
```

then it works for me.  Generic TLSv1 fails with the same error as above, versions higher than 1.0 give me an error about "unsupported protocol", SSLv3 says "alert handshake failure", and SSLv2 simply isn't supported on my machine.

Comment: Yes, it's an OpenSSL bug.
Should be version 1.0.1h or higher.
Find it here: http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?5,924339